How do I set a userid field to be the same as the documentID?
I've been searching for hours and no luck. I'm trying to set userId to the generated document ID. I know it's redundant, but for this project, we are not allowed to use Firebase Auth so I cannot use uid. I've been trying many solutions to no avail. I just need a way to grab the ID so I can pass it into another activity. I want to know why it's different, and how to make it the same.
I tried this, and this was the result:
val user: MutableMap<String, Any> = HashMap()
        val userID = userCollection.document().id
        user["userId"] = userID

This was the result.

You can use the DocumentId annotation in front of the field to:

Mark a POJO property to be automatically populated with the document's ID.


how would i be able to implement that using kotlin?

Create a POJO (data) class, add an ID property, and annotate it with DocumentId. That's it.

Hey there. Have you tried my solution above, does it work for you?
